# What is intellect-consciousness and why is it different from intellect itself?

Tags: philosophy, pratityasamutpada, consciousness

In SN 35.93 quoted below, it reads intellect-consciousness arises in dependence on the intellect and ideas, but if this consciousness is also a thinking about the work of intellect on ideas then it in itself is an intellect. and if so we have to look for another consciousness which higher and the search continues ad-infinitum.

This, of course, is not my own though it's a classic platonic thinkers response to Descartes's misguided saying Cogito ergo sum ( I think, therefore I am),  quoted below is from Plotinos Ennead Book Nine explaining the relation of intellect and consciousness.

---

[SN 35.93 Dvaya Sutta: A Pair](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn35/sn35.093.than.html)

> "In dependence on the intellect & ideas, there arises
>   intellect-consciousness. The intellect is inconstant, changeable, of a
>   nature to become otherwise. Ideas are inconstant, changeable, of a
>   nature to become otherwise. Thus this pair is both wavering &
>   fluctuating — inconstant, changeable, of a nature to become otherwise.

---

*PLOTINOS: - SECOND ENNEAD, BOOK NINE.*

> Though there be a difference between thinking, and thinking that one
>   thinks, these two nevertheless constitute a single intuitive
>   consciousness of its actualizations. It would be ridiculous to deny
>   such a consciousness to veritable Intelligence. It is, therefore, the
>   same Intelligence that thinks, and that thinks that it thinks.
>   Otherwise, there would be two principles, of which the one would have
>   thought, and the other consciousness of thought. The second would
>   doubtless differ from the first, but would not be the real thinking
>   principle. A mere logical distinction between thought and
>   consciousness of thought would not establish the (actual) differences
>   between two . Further, we shall have to
>   consider whether it be possible to conceive of an Intelligence which
>   would exclusively think, without any accompanying consciousness of its
>   thought. If we ourselves who are entirely devoted to practical
>   activity and discursive reason were in such a condition, we would,
>   even if otherwise considered sensible, be insane. But as true
>   Intelligence thinks itself in its thoughts, and as the
>   intelligible, far from being outside of Intelligence, is Intelligence
>   itself, Intelligence, by thinking, possesses itself, and necessarily
>   sees itself. When Intelligence sees itself, it does not see itself
>   as unintelligent, but as intelligent. Therefore in the first
>   actualization of thought, Intelligence has the thought and
>   consciousness of thought, two things that form but a single one; not
>   even logically is this a duality. If Intelligence always thinks what
>   it is, is there any reason to separate, even by a simple logical
>   distinction, thought from the consciousness of thought? The absurdity
>   of the doctrine we are controverting will be still more evident if we
>   suppose that a third intelligence is conscious that the second
>   intelligence is conscious of the thought of the first; we might thus
>   go on to infinity

Answer (score 5):

This is just bad translation. "Consciousness" is the common word for `vijnana`. A better translation of `vijnana` is "(subjective) experience". Meaning, you see something => you recognize it => you make sense of it => you experience it.

"Intellect" is how they usually translate `manas` or mind.

So "Intellect-consciousness" or `mano-vijnana`, is therefore the subjective experience of what's going on one's own mind. It's when you "see" what you're thinking about etc. I think it's called re-representation in modern cognitive science.

It does not require a higher mind or anything like that. Based on my meditation experience, it works as a cycle. Normally the input from sense organs goes to memory to find matching associations, this is how recognition happens, the basis of `vijnana`. With manovijnana, instead of the sensory organs, our attention grabs data from short term memory, finds matches in long term memory, puts that back in short term memory - voila, manovijnana.

Answer (score 3):

Consciousness ('vinnana') is not thinking. Consciousness is experiencing or knowing.

> *Dependent on intellect & ideas, intellect-consciousness arises. The meeting of the three is contact. With contact as a requisite
>   condition, there is feeling. What one feels, one perceives (labels in
>   the mind). What one perceives, one thinks about. What one thinks
>   about, one objectifies.*
>
> *MN 18*

The term 'intellect-consciousness' is merely a name for a certain type of consciousness (knowing), similar to when describing different types of paint as 'red paint', 'blue paint', 'house paint', 'wall paint', 'outdoor paint', etc. Intellect-consciousness' refers to a consciousness that arises to experience the intellect & its products.

The 'intellect' (called 'mano') is not 'the power of knowing'. 'Mano' refers to the power of intelligence, reason, thinking & decision making, such as described in verse 1 of the Dhammapada:

> ***Mano***pubbaṅgamā dhammā **mano**seṭṭhā **mano**mayā. **Mana**sā ce paduṭṭhena bhāsati vā karoti vā Tato naṃ dukkhamanveti cakkaṃ'va
>   vahato padaṃ.
>
> *Mind precedes all mental states. Mind is their chief; they are all mind-wrought. If with an impure mind a person speaks or acts suffering
>   follows him like the wheel that follows the foot of the ox.*

As described, above, 'mano' (translated as 'intellect') is that which thinks & acts rather than is that which knows & experiences.

It helps understanding to view '*consciousness*' as a '*mirror*' and to view '*intellect & ideas*' as objects reflected in that mirror.

Comment: Could you please elaborate further ... if Consciousness is knowing ... how is that different from intellect which is the power of knowing?

Comment: isn't knowing the perception of a feeling?